# How to get the checkbox value in php html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table showing database values as shown here:

```
<?php
       while ($single = $output->fetch_assoc()):?> 
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $single['Dptname']; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['firstname']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['lastname']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['email']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['phnumber']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['provider']; ?> </td>
     <td style="display: none"> <?php echo $single['id']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="Dptadmin" id="Dptadmin" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="superuser" id="superuser" value="1"></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn b1 editbtn" data-toggle="modal" value="" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">  </i> </button>
        <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $single['id'];?>" class="b2"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.editbtn').on('click', function(){
        $('#editmodal').modal('show');
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $tr.children('td').map(function(){
          return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        console.log(data);
        $('#Dptname').val(data[0]);
        $('#firstname').val(data[1]);
        $('#lastname').val(data[2]);
        $('#email').val(data[3]);
        $('#phnumber').val(data[4]);
        $('#provider').val(data[5]);
        $('#userid').val(data[6]);
        $('#userid').val(data[6]);
        $('#Dptadmin').val(data[7]);
    });
 });
```

Tried:-

```
 $('.Dptadmin').on('click', function(){
     $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $tr.children('td').map(function(){
          return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        console.log(data);
        $('#userid').val(data[6]);
        var val = $(this).find(":checkbox['<?php echo $single['Dadmin']; ?>']").val();
        console.log(val);
```

As above jQuery, from `console.log(data)` I'm getting the value of selected TD, but not getting checkbox value. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you only want the value of checkbox then you no need to write that much query code.  you can simply get the values of the checkbox by
  $('.Dptadmin').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  })

Comment: hi @HarsimranjitSingh. thank you for your response. I'm kind of new to this. can you please provide little code about that.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get the value of your checkbox when it is clicked  then use the below code

```
  $('.Dptadmin').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: yes, this works correctly. but my requirement is I need to get the id of the particular row of which checkbox is checked. because I need to store that in my MySQL database, for that I have written ajax call. so here with the checkbox clicked i want the related userid also which is placed in that td

Comment: for that first of all add ID in your HTML TR code, your <tr> tag doesn't have any ID
you need to give it a id and then your problem can be solved by using 
 var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution on my own. thank you for your support your ideas are made me think beyond. here is my solution.

```
 $('.Dadmin').on('click', function(){
         $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $tr.children('td').map(function(){
          return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        var userid = data[6];
        var admin = $('#Dadmin').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'makeadmin.php',
        data: {
            userid : userid,
            admin : admin,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.length);
        },
        });
    })
```

html

```
 <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $single['Dptname']; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['firstname']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['lastname']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['email']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['phnumber']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $single['provider']; ?> </td>
     <td style="display: none"> <?php echo $single['id']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="Dadmin" id="Dadmin" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="superuser" id="superuser" value="1"></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn b1 editbtn" data-toggle="modal" value="" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">  </i> </button>
        <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $single['id'];?>" class="b2"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

here only i changed `$('#userid').val(data[6]);` to `var userid = data[6];`

hope so this will help somebody. thank you all once.

Comment: still i will say stop using `id` to get value because if you have multiple rows then `id's` will crash you will not get corresponding column data. Try my answer once.